# Is it possible to program a form of 2factor authentication for certain Active Directory users?

Tags: python, windows, powershell, active-directory

I'm looking into setting up a way where certain staff would need to input a code from an sms text when they log into their PCs on our company network. Whenever I tried looking this up, all I got were paid services to do it for you. We're on a budget and I'd like to see if I could just make one myself in like Python or Powershell or something.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly. Yes, it is possible!

But I am not entirely familiar with what is been "free" here, but I see there is an open source server for sending sms.

https://github.com/typpo/textbelt

My understanding is that if you run the server yourself, the library provide you with an easy way to send SMS from it, but the pricing is not so bad either. The top offer at textbelt seems `$45/5000` .

You want to have some code to DIY 2FA, you might wanna read more about it in other websites and tutorials, so you can avoid some sort of attacks, there is planty on the internet about it, for example:

https://www.twilio.com/learn/account-security/the-pitfalls-of-developing-your-own-2fa

If you are not using any library, the curl examlpe is pretty straight forward to implement a module or a script around it.

Good luck!